# Debugging nuget symbol package in Vs 2015

Tags: nuget-package, symbols, visual-studio-2015, symbol-server

I am facing problem in debugging nuget symbol package. I have tried all the way but no success

I followed

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages

site for creating, settingup API key, pushing/publishing nuget and symbol packages to nuget and symbol server.

I have published/pushed nuget "symbol package" to nuget server and installed to my console application(consumer), so that I can have PDB and src files for debugging.

For debugging setup, I followed David Bebbo's blog:

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/04/easy-way-to-publish-nuget-packages-with.html

But I am still unable to debug. I am attaching sample code which is creating and consuming nuget package.

Please find the sample applications URL:

[Sample Application URL][1]: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjY6G2UYhZNIgn7mMd_7jCyWMV_a

Please refer to folder NugetPOC > Source : This is a class library application, is used to create nuget and symbol packages.

NugetPOC > Consumer: Is used to install and use symbol packages for debugging purpose.

Your help will be really appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue with loading symbols?